Dynamic Webscraping in R
I am trying to scrape information about orbits for asteroids in R. I have tried rvest and selectorgadget, however the website is dynamic. The website is: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=2006%20WP1
I am wanting to get the data for the Osculating Orbital Elements under the Orbit Parameters drop down shown here:

I am not very familiar with html or json, so I am looking for help downloading this table into R.

The RSelenium package may do what you want.  It runs a browser (real or virtual) which looks to the web site like a regular browser.  The main issues are that it needs to have a driver to match the exact version of the browser that you use; this has been tricky lately.

Use their API.
As an example of how to use the API, inspecting the page we can see the parameters used and recreate them (although I have changed it to use the direct identifier rather than a search string because it is quicker):
# Query parameters
params <- list(
  spk              = "3359266",
  `alt-des`        = 1,
  `alt-orbits`     = 1,
  `ca-data`        = 1,
  `ca-time`        = "both",
  `ca-tunc`        = "both",
  `cd-epoch`       = 1,
  `cd-tp`          = 1,
  discovery        = 1,
  `full-prec`      = 1,
  `nv-fmt`         = "both",
  `orbit-defs`     = 1,
  `phys-par`       = 1,
  `r-notes`        = 1,
  `r-observer`     = 1,
  `radar-obs`      = 1,
  sat              = 1,
  `vi-data`        = 1,
  www              = 1
)

# Make query string
param_string <- paste0(names(params), "=", params, collapse = "&")

Now retrieve the data:
dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(
  sprintf("https://ssd-api.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.api?%s", param_string)
  )

# Inspect 
dat$orbit$elements

       sigma  name                                                 title units                value  label
1   .0010672     e                                          eccentricity  <NA>    .6067433473394845      e
2   .0036921     a                                       semi-major axis    au    1.706954591882637      a
3  .00037377     q                                   perihelion distance    au    .6712712490472621      q
4   .0093907     i inclination; angle with respect to x-y ecliptic plane   deg    5.896394792692075      i
5  .00085394    om                       longitude of the ascending node   deg    234.2975070934102   node
6   .0079426     w                                argument of perihelion   deg    98.19292045631209   peri
7    .086629    ma                                          mean anomaly   deg    22.10748390629943      M
8    .033722    tp                            time of perihelion passage   TDB 2454008.477177134853     tp
9       <NA> tp_cd                            time of perihelion passage   TDB 2006-Sep-29.97717713     tp
10    2.6428   per                               sidereal orbital period     d    814.5755667075963 period
11  .0014339     n                                           mean motion deg/d    .4419479477577152      n
12  .0059322    ad                                     aphelion distance    au    2.742637934718012      Q


To complete, using rvest read_html_live :
### Packages
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
)

### Parse and extract the table with html_live and XPath
dd=read_html_live("https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=2006%20WP1")
s=html_elements(dd,xpath = "(//table)[1]") %>% html_table()

### TP and period rows are merged. To fix this, we create new lines.
rows=c("tp","period")
labels=list(c("TDB","TDB"),c("d","y"))

nasa=function(x,y){
  f=html_elements(dd,xpath = paste0('(//table)[1]//tr[contains(.,"',x,'")]/td[2]')) %>%
    html_text2() %>% 
  str_split(pattern = "\n") %>%
    unlist()
  
  g=html_elements(dd,xpath = paste0('(//table)[1]//tr[contains(.,"',x,'")]/td[3]')) %>%
    html_text2() %>% 
    str_split(pattern = "\n") %>%
    unlist()
  
tibble(Element=x,Value=f,`Uncertainty (1-sigma)`=g, Units=y)
}

temp=map2(rows,labels,nasa)
pp=bind_rows(temp)

### Merge the new lines with the table and delete old rows
output=s[[1]] %>% 
  add_row(pp,.before = 8) %>%
  slice(-c(12,13))

Output :
# A tibble: 13 × 4
   Element Value                `Uncertainty (1-sigma)` Units  
   <chr>   <chr>                <chr>                   <chr>  
 1 e       0.6067433473394845   .0010672                ""     
 2 a       1.706954591882637    .0036921                "au"   
 3 q       0.6712712490472621   .00037377               "au"   
 4 i       5.896394792692075    .0093907                "deg"  
 5 node    234.2975070934102    .00085394               "deg"  
 6 peri    98.19292045631209    .0079426                "deg"  
 7 M       22.10748390629943    .086629                 "deg"  
 8 tp      2454008.477177134853 .033722                 "TDB"  
 9 tp      2006-Sep-29.97717713 .033722                 "TDB"  
10 period  814.5755667075963    2.6428                  "d"    
11 period  2.230186356488970    7.2356e-3               "y"    
12 n       0.4419479477577152   .0014339                "deg/d"
13 Q       2.742637934718012    .0059322                "au"  

